# TypeError on Angular9 "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatchEvent')

Tags: angular, typeerror, angular9

I am following a lesson about Angular in course on Udemy and in console I have this error

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatchEvent')
at :2:27*

this is the code from the app component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare global {
  interface Document {
    monetization?:any;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'web-monetization';
  monetized=false;

  ngOnInit() {
      if (document.monetization){
        document.monetization.addEventListener('monetizationstart', ()=> {
          this.monetized=true;
        });
      }
  }

  pay() {
    const event =new Event('monetizationstart');
    document.monetization.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Some coding tutorial <button class="button is-link" (click)="pay()">Simulate payment</button></h1>
    <div class="box">
      <h2 class="subtitle is-2">
        The first example
      </h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla varius metus quis dapibus lacinia. Proin faucibus faucibus nunc, non eleifend metus rutrum quis. Nullam molestie turpis id eros vulputate eleifend.
      </p>
      <code *ngIf="monetized"  class="is-block">
        const text= 'Here is text for the first example'; console.log(text);
      </code>
      <div *ngIf="!monetized" class="notification">
        You Need Monetization to see the code
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h2 class="subtitle is-2">
        The second part
      </h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla varius metus quis dapibus lacinia. Proin faucibus faucibus nunc, non eleifend metus rutrum quis. Nullam molestie turpis id eros vulputate eleifend.
      </p>
      <code *ngIf="monetized" class="is-block">
        const text= 'Here is text for the first example'; console.log(text);
      </code>
      <div *ngIf="!monetized" class="notification">
        You Need Monetization to see the code
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

I am sure to have copied the rigth instruction so I don't know why I see the error

Comment: add optional chaining -> document?.monetization?.addEventListener

Comment: I tried but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In pay method you don't have a check if monetization is available like you have in ngOnInit. In your browser monetization is undefined. See these states here :-

https://webmonetization.org/docs/api/#states

You can add a pollyfill :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-monetization-polyfill

Comment: I was following a tutorial, so I have declared the monetization in the meta propieties of index.html in this way:  <meta name="monetization" content="$twitter.xrptipbot.com/doumly"/> Using the same link that I have seen in the tutorial.